# Twilio REST API - Unable to buy a twilio number for a sub account‏

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, twilio

I've developed a Web application in ASP.net web Forms (.net v4.0) which uses the REST API. The problem we are facing is that when we run the application on the developer machine everything works great but when we deploy the same application on the Windows Server 2008R2, the process of creating a sub account and buying a new twilio number for the newly created sub account does not completes. Only sub account gets created but no new number. If you could help me to get this problem fixed, I will really appreciate this. The code is as following:

```
    ArrayList AccountInformation = new ArrayList();
    var client = new Twilio.TwilioRestClient(this.ParentAccountSid, this.ParentAuthToken);

    var subaccount = client.CreateSubAccount(email);               

    var subaccountClient = new Twilio.TwilioRestClient(subaccount.Sid, subaccount.AuthToken);

    var number = subaccountClient.AddIncomingPhoneNumber(new Twilio.PhoneNumberOptions() { AreaCode = "412" } );

    AccountInformation.Add(number.PhoneNumber.ToString());
    AccountInformation.Add(subaccount.AuthToken.ToString());
    AccountInformation.Add(subaccount.Sid.ToString());
    AccountInformation.Add(subaccount.Uri.ToString());
```

Also, any specific changes/installation on the web server machine required, please do tell.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's the same AccountSid/AuthToken on both local and remote? Is the latest version of the code deployed? The code looks right so my guess is it's something external to it.

Comment: Yes, it's the same AccountSid/AuthToken on both machines. and also the latest code is deployed on the server. Something external like what?

Comment: I meant external like configuration, etc. Is there anything in `number.RestException` after you call `subaccountClient.AddIncomingPhoneNumber(...)`?

Comment: If you're on the latest version RestException may be null every time (sorry, there's a bug in the lib we need to fix). Let me know what you find and I'll check back in the morning.

Comment: I tried to log anything after var subaccount = client.CreateSubAccount(email); but I think the method returns right after executing the above mentioned line... I tried to catch the exception but it doesn't catch anything...

Comment: When you run it in production, does the new subaccount show up in your dashboard (in the gray bar on the left)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7418/discussion-between-taunsvi-and-john-sheehan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new release fixed our problem